# Ferrite beads as power rail in opamp breakout analog input circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, adc, components

i'm designing a small breakout boards that is used to interface some external sensors (voltage and current) to a MCU.

In order to get better results, i'm using an external dedicated ADC, the [ADS1115](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1113.pdf?ts=1615034230310&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), i've seen the implementation of Adafruit in this breakout: [here](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1085) and [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-4-channel-adc-breakouts/downloads) there are the schematic and pcb design.

My question is pretty simple: can i use the output GND and VDD from ferrite beads in order to power up my circuit? it is a bad choice? it will generate some issue power the opamp's from the output of ferrite beads? consider that the analog inputs are only 0...20mA and 0...10V inputs from sensors.

Here is the circuit schematic, very simple and effective:

[image: sch]

And here it's the Ferrite bead electrical characteristics used ([MMZ2012Y152B](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1810132021_TDK-MMZ2012Y152B_C21517.pdf)):

[image: ferrite]

Comment: Why ?  Have you computed ripple and spectrum? and attenuation?

Comment: What else will share power on those lines. I can only see one thing, and suspect there are more. We need **all** of the information to best answer you. And why are those filters there? The answer to that question will also affect your answer.

Comment: There are only two NCS2006 dual opamp configured as reported in the original post for a total of 4 inputs. Nothing else in the schematic. Honestly I don't know why those filters are placed here from adafruit (I've simply copied them into my schematic), anyway, this "side question" will be a good starting point.

Comment: Couple things to check for at L1/C5/L2. Firstly, the LC resonance with the ferrite. In the ferrite datasheet (page 4), look at the "ZXR" chart for your ferrite part. As is typical, it is almost entirely inductive thru 10MHz+. You can estimate the inductance roughly from the chart, although the chart is with the ferrite unloaded, so it may be lower in practice. Let's just say it's on the order of 1uH. That will resonate with the 1uF cap in the 100kHz ballpark. Maybe matters, maybe not, just something to be aware of. It can be damped if it is an issue.

Comment: Also, the ferrite in the ground path for the MCU can occasionally bring up issues, again in the case of the MCU driving something capacitive with spiky return currents. If you see ground-bounce type symptoms, it's something to check. Again, not necessarily a problem